# Deleting Customize Options Value in Magento 2.2 wiped out all remaining options

Tags: magento2.2

I am working on a project in which we have upgraded from Magento2.1.8 to Magento2.2.0.

Customization Options were working fine and now on Magento2.2.0 we are facing an issue.

For example: 
we have 2 options

- a
- b

We have 3 option values for each option

- a
  -- a1
  -- a2
  -- a3
- b
  -- b1
  -- b2
  -- b3

when we edit product, if we delete a2 or a3 all options of B will be wiped out.

While it was working fine on Magento2.1.8.

Any clue or guideline to fix this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You need to change `app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Value.php`or vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Option/Value.php file at around line 211.

Just remove or comment `$this->delete();` inside  `saveValues()` function and it will work properly. Hope it helps you thanks

Comment: I haven't try that and I think in this way, when we will be going to delete it will not work ? am i right ?